# Sort array of objects by int, then by alphabetical

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array with some various information in it regarding state traits and need to modify it in a few ways. First I need to sort it by area then by name if the area is the same. So I use parseInt to get the actual int instead of the string but now I'm lost. How do I pull off this sort? I also need to find the most populated / least populated states and store that in variables.

```
(function() {
'use strict';

var states = [{
    "name": "Alaska",
    "area": "663,268 sq mi",
    "population": 735132
}, {
    "name": "California",
    "area": "163,696 sq mi",
    "population": 38332521
}, {
    "name": "oregon",
    "area": "98,381 sq mi",
    "population": 3899353
}, {
    "name": "washington",
    "area": "71,300 sq mi",
    "population": 6971406
}];

var moddedStates = {};
for (var i = 0; i < states.length; i++) {
    var area = parseInt(states[i].area);

}
}());
```

Comment: [Array.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: Write your own compare function, as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sorting-objects-in-an-array-by-a-field-value-in-javascript). Note that parseInt alone is insufficient to get the area of a state, as it will stop at the first comma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this snippet does everything you wanted. Note the use of `replace` to account for commas, and the use of `parseFloat` instead of `parseInt`, just in case some sizes include digits to the right of the decimal. (Probably not an issue when comparing sizes of U.S. states, but a good habit to get into nonetheless...)

```js
(function() {
    'use strict';
    
    var states = [{
        "name": "Alaska",
        "area": "663,268 sq mi",
        "population": 735132
    }, {
        "name": "California",
        "area": "163,696 sq mi",
        "population": 38332521
    }, {
        "name": "oregon",
        "area": "98,381 sq mi",
        "population": 3899353
    }, {
        "name": "washington",
        "area": "71,300 sq mi",
        "population": 6971406
    }];
    
    var mostPopulated = null;
    var leastPopulated = null;

    states.sort(function (a, b) {
        var aArea = parseFloat(a.area.replace(/,/g, ''));
        var bArea = parseFloat(b.area.replace(/,/g, ''));
        if (aArea < bArea) return -1;
        else if (bArea < aArea) return 1;
        else if (a.name < b.name) return -1;
        else if (b.name < a.name) return 1;
        else return 0;
    });
    
    for (var i = 0, len = states.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (!mostPopulated || states[i].population > mostPopulated.population) {
            mostPopulated = states[i];
        }
        if (!leastPopulated || states[i].population < leastPopulated.population) {
            leastPopulated = states[i];
        }
    }
    
    console.log(states);
    console.log(mostPopulated);
    console.log(leastPopulated);
}());
```

Comment: thanks! This helps a lot. I'm going to research the return values of the compare function to understand what's going on better.

Comment: No problem. I usually find MDN's documentation to be very helpful for JavaScript, HTML, and CSS. Example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort